# Looping through HTML form data via JSON arrays/objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have been scouring this website and the internet for a few hours now, and asked a question earlier which got me at least a step further.. However I am really struggling to understand how to save multiple arrays to my `localStorage`.

I can understand the process using a hardcoded array, but as soon as I try to implement the `localStorage` data, I can't understand what to do.

Heres what I have tried so far (with help from another SO user):

```
$("#submit").click(function () {

    // prepare
    var formData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
    // get all stored as Array []
    var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings') || '[]');

    for (formData = 0; formData < localStorage.length; formData++) {
    // insert and save
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify([formData]));
    }
    
});
```

It works fine without the for loop, however when I resubmit the form with new data it replaces it rather than creates a new index?

Basically I am trying to create an appointment scheduler for dog walking and I need to be able to view each booking, amend, delete, and of course view the bookings (all client side - no databases).

Should I be initialising my array first? How to I approach the for loop? Any help is appreciated as I want to learn but I have been at this for hours with no luck.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (nor a "JSON Array")

Comment: Alright..? Thats what I know them as and I'm new to this. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: The loop doesn't make any sense. You're overwriting `formData` with `0`, and then you call `.setItem()` `localStorage.length` times with always the same key (`bookings`) and store `[ <current value of formData> ]` as its content.

Comment: Find a way on how to store all the appointments in a structured way (e.g. an array). If you've found a suitable solution you can then store that "thing" (which might be an array of objects, or an object of <something>) in `localStorage` with only one call of `.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify(<"thing">))`

Comment: Thank you, I understand that but I am not sure how to implement it, I am able to get one record but then if I make a new record it replaces the old record. I know my code isn't correct but I just wanted to show my thinking/working in hopes someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like following.
Save new values in the the previously stored values in variable and update the local storage at the end.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {

    var formData = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
    var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings') || '[]');
   
    for (formData = 0; formData < localStorage.length; formData++) {
        bookings.push(formData)   
    }
    localStorage.setItem("bookings", JSON.stringify(bookings));
});
```

Comment: This now isn't working, I haven't made any changes but for some reason now just giving me an array of numbers?